# How do I "Spawn" Beehives in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that there is a chance that you can find a beehive in a flower forest in Minecraft and that you can spawn one in with a sapling next to a flower, but what are the chances that a beehive will actually spawn next to a tree (Grown by a player), and how exactly do I do it?

Comment: What you're asking is a method to spawn *bee nests*. Bee hives are crafted with planks and bees wax (easy to farm automatically) and can be populated by breeding bees - feeding flowers (any small flowers) to two bees to produce a baby bee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 5% Chance.
However, for that chance to start happening, you'd need to make sure that a flower is no more than two blocks away from your oak/birch saplings, and that the flower and sapling are on the same elevation.

As quoted by the MineCraft Gamepedia;

"5%
Oak or birch trees grown from saplings that are within 2 blocks of any flower on the same y-level have 5% chance to grow with a bee nest containing 1–3 bees."

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact chances there will be a beehive on a tree once you grow it but you can just use the command `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:beehive` and it will spawn one wherever you are standing.

Answer (score -2):

Ok hope this helps.  If you get a hive Silk touch it if no bees are naturally flying around. Once you replace it the bees should spawn. This is what I did yesterday twice.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! But OP is asking about beehives, not the bees.